# EXTJS 4.1.1. iframes reloads when switching tabs in TabPanel on Firefox:

Tags: iframe, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, tabpanel

I've got a problem with **PDF's** in the TabPanel (only on Firefox). They are **reloading everytime I switch tabs**. The **PDF** is **in a iframe**.

Because of it the user can not compare two PDF files. When you click a tab with a PDF it loads 10 seconds, then you switch to a second tab and it also loads 10 seconds and so on....

I know this problem with Firefox has been around for years (which relates IFRAME, OBJECT, elements, FF reinitializes the objects, if their size changes).

It cannot be that there is no solution for this problem.

However, I have not found any for Extjs4 yet.

It would be great if someone could help me with it.

Comment: Way back I run into this issue and it seemed that it was related to showing hiding iframes in Firefox. Maybe it is worth to try Ext windows instead of tab panel to compare pdfs.

Comment: @Saki thanks, a window is a option to load PDF files (not optimal, but). I will try to play with the css-settings for the Container in the TabPanel (style:{} and hideMode). Let's see what can it bring..